# Data gets corrupted with DB2 configured with 819 code page / ISO8859-1 code set

Tags: db2

I have a problem with DB2 configured with 819 code page / ISO8859-1 code set. I am trying to save some data like bullet point •  or even double quote "" from a text editor of my application and it gets damaged. While render it back to UI it shows as -> We are using JDBC and Jack Rabbit to persist the data into DB. Even the data gets damaged if we try to insert using JDBC with prepared statements. If the DB2 is configured with 1208 code page / UTF-8 code set it works fine.

We are using db2jcc_license_cu.jar and db2jcc-4.13.127.jar

Also the same features having DB2 configured with 819 code page / ISO8859-1 code set is working for another version of application where we use SQL Access / DLL instead of JDBC/Jackrabbit

Could someone help me out how it can work with DB2 having 819 code page / ISO8859-1 code set

Thanks !

Comment: What's your workstation operating system (where the jdbc is running) and locale ?   Your application (jdbc) needs to use the same encoding as the database (utf-8 / 1208).

Comment: It is windows operating system and locale is English US

Comment: It works when the DB2-database encoding is UTF-8 because then the Windows special characters like double-quote or bullet get successfully converted to UTF-8.  Those characters may not have a codepoint in ISO8859-1 .

Comment: I have download db2jcc4.jar from IBM support, fix pack: DSClients--jdbc_sqlj-11.1.2.2-FP002. It is under DB2 version 11.1 and driver version is 4.23.42 and jar is found under \\v11.1.2fp2_jdbc_sqlj.tar.gz\v11.1.2fp2_jdbc_sqlj.tar\jdbc_sqlj\db2_db2driver_for_jdbc_sqlj.zip\ 
There are two jars db2jcc.jar and db2jcc4.jar, I have used db2jcc4.jar but still the problem is there
FYI: We are using com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver 
Could someone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506chong/).

Also you should arrange to upgrade your db2jcc4.jar file to a currently supported version . At todays date that is 4.23.42 (available from IBM fix central , in any DB2-client at version 11.1 fixpack 2 ).

Comment: I have download db2jcc4.jar from IBM support, fix pack: DSClients--jdbc_sqlj-11.1.2.2-FP002. It is under DB2 version 11.1 and driver version is 4.23.42 and jar is found under \\v11.1.2fp2_jdbc_sqlj.tar.gz\v11.1.2fp2_jdbc_sqlj.tar\jdbc_sqlj\db2_db2driver_for_jdbc_sqlj.zip\ 
There are two jars db2jcc.jar and db2jcc4.jar, I have used db2jcc4.jar but still the problem is there
FYI: We are using com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver 
Could someone please suggest?

Comment: You also need to ensure that the jvm you are using is up to date.  Verify that in the exception you get (after updating db2jcc4.jar) shows the new driver version (i.e. should NOT be 4.13.* ).